# Low FPS with SurfaceView on Android 5

Tags: android, surfaceview

I'm doing a pretty standard drawing using SurfaceView.
The code is running smoothly ~60fps on most devices. BUT -
On Android 5, I'm getting real bad performance.

Any clue why?

```
class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread thread = null;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    volatile boolean running = false;


    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        surfaceHolder = getHolder();
    }

    public void onResumeMySurfaceView(){
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public void onPauseMySurfaceView(){
        boolean retry = true;
        running = false;
        while(retry){
            try {
                thread.join();
                retry = false;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(running){
            if(surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()){
                Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                // drawing
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're running all your code on your UI thread?

Comment: No, it runs on a different thread.

Comment: Maybe using the built-in threading handlers such as ASyncTask for short operations and Services for long running threads would help? I'm not exactly an expert but from what I gathered from reading Android 4 Game Programming writing your own threads is possible, but then you ignore all the optimisation built into the defaults with unpredictable results. Romain Guy, android dev team member, has some great videos explaining all kinds of stuff regarding optimization. Perhaps he has something regarding this subject.

Comment: You should also look into TraceView, Eclipse Memory Analyzer and Hierarchy Viewer to see if there's anything you can do to spread out and reduce your performance requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that the same hardware has different performance with and without the Android 5.0 upgrade?  Or is this about two different devices?  Bear in mind that Canvas rendering on a SurfaceView surface is done entirely in software, so devices with higher pixel counts will suffer unless they have the CPU and bus bandwidth to make up for it.

Comment: Same device (same hardware)

Comment: late reply, but I also had this problem on a Huawei Device with marshmallow. It turned out that creating a new Paint() in onDraw() caused this problem...it´s also stated on the developer site but can´t find again...